# How to letterbox crop without setting the viewport in Directx 11

Tags: c++, direct3d11

My application has a fixed aspect ratio (2.39:1 letterbox) besides the screen native aspect ratio. I'm trying to achieve this fixed size in fullscreen, **without creating a larger set of render targets, and applying a viewport crop on them**; just like having a smaller buffer, and blitting it to the center of the window. The reason for that, the effect pipeline uses multiple render targets, which are set to the render area size, and If I do set the viewport instead, I have to mess around with the uvs/coordiantes and so, and will look ugly or be faulty.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 when using `CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow` or `CreateSwapChainForComposition`, you can make use of `DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH` which has the system automatically do this.

Otherwise, you have to render to your own render target texture and then do a final quad draw to the swapchain with the desired location for letterbox.